# MVVM Relay Command triggers before Silverlight NumericUpDown changes value

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, mvvm-light, silverlight-toolkit, numericupdown

If you have a Silverlight Toolkit NumericUpDown control binded to a MVVM property and a RelayCommand trigger set (any event), the command is called before NumericUpDown changes MVVM property value. This means, you can not use the new (changed) value with you method/action/command...

XAML:

```
<inputToolkit:NumericUpDown x:Name="testNum" Value="{Binding RegisterForm, Mode=TwoWay}">
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
  <i:EventTrigger EventName="ValueChanged">
    <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DoSomethingCommand}"/>
  </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
</inputToolkit:NumericUpDown>
```

MVVM (C#):

```
DoSomethingCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
            {
                OtherRegisterForm = RegisterForm;
            });
```

In this case, if you have v value 0 and you input a new value 123 in NumericUpDown control it triggers the "DoSomethingCommand" before "RaisePropertyChange" event on MVVM property.
"OtherRegisterForm" would be 0 and not 123.

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

oh boy, wasn't easy but here u are :

xaml part :

```
<toolkit:NumericUpDown Value="{Binding SomeNumber}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="ValueChanged">
                <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding MyCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </toolkit:NumericUpDown>
```

and cs code :

```
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    public double SomeNumber { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        SomeNumber = 10;
        MyCommand = new RelayCommand<RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double>>(myActionMethod);
    }

    public RelayCommand<RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double>> MyCommand { get; set; }

    public void myActionMethod(RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> arg)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(arg.NewValue.ToString());
    }
}
```

hope that helps, Arek